# Speeding up transforming DB select to XML with Mule 3.5

Tags: mule

I'm trying to convert data from a database query to XML. There are about 20,000 rows. It takes something like ten minutes to run, which seems unreasonably slow to me.

I noticed that `eventContext` has a `getOutputStream` method, but that <s>throws an exception when I try to call it</s> returns null whenever I call it. I also don't have the Java expertise to know the best way to stream the XML, though I'm sure I can look that up, I'd appreciate any hints there.

The structure of the XML I want is something like:

```
<myElements>
    <myElement>
        <someId>123454</someId>
        <someProperty>Some Value</someProperty>
        <mySubElements>
            <mySubElement>
                <anotherId>67890</anotherId>
                <anotherProperty>Another Value</anotherProperty>
            </mySubElement>
            <mySubElement>
                <anotherId>24680</anotherId>
                <anotherProperty>Yet Another Value</anotherProperty>
            </mySubElement>
        </mySubElements>
    </myElement>
</myElements>
```

The output of my query is something like this:

```
SOME_ID    SOME_PROPERTY      ANOTHER_ID    ANOTHER_PROPERTY
12345      Some Value         67890         Another Value
12345      Some Value         24680         Yet Another Value
```

I'm using the `component` transformer, and my code there looks something like this:

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    List queryResults = (List) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element myElements = doc.createElement("myElements");
    doc.appendChild(myElements);

    Element myElement = null;
    Integer currentSomeId = null;

    for (Integer i = 0; i < queryResults.size(); i++)
    {
        Map queryRow = (Map) queryResults.get(i);
        if (!queryRow.get("SOME_ID").equals(currentSomeId))
        {
            myElement = doc.createElement("myElement");
            /* populate my element, including with an empty mySubElements */
        }

        Element mySubElement = doc.createElement("myElement");
        /* populate mySubElement */
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(baos));
    eventContext.getMessage().setPayload(doc);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

My mule flow looks like this:

```
<flow name="MyElementsFlow-Https">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="${webapi.myelements.path}" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="MyElementsFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>

<flow name="MyElementsFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <db:select config-ref="DB-Connector" doc:name="Select">
        <db:template-query-ref name="select-template" />
    </db:select>
    <component class="myJavaComponent" doc:name="To XML"/>
</flow>
```

**edit**: I thought I'd try setting the HTTP connector to `responseStreamingMode="ALWAYS"` and the DB select to `streaming="true"`, but when I do that, the iterator I get in my payload returns `false` from `hasNext()`, and  `next()` throws an exception about being closed.

**edit**: Corrected result of calling `getOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to load an XML which is unreasonably big into Memory (by using dom), the 10 minutes you're experiencing is probably spent most in garbage collection, so the first trivial thing to do to improve this is to add more heap to your wrapper.conf, you can do this only if the process will run in very low load.

I would suggest you to try a divide and conquer technique, maybe using your disk as intermediate storage.

You can use stax to stream XML

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html

Comment: Thanks, @Juan Alberto López Cavall. I'll give your suggestions a try. Do you know if there's a way to stream right to the output stream for Mule, or will I have to write to a byte array at the end anyway?

Comment: Or, is your suggested not to use the payload mechanism at all and tell Mule to load an XML file from disk that I had written to with what I would have put into the byte array?

Comment: If you return an xml stream, then mule's xml module can take care of transforming it into something readable, but there are various approaches you may take.